# How to find affected rows, after an update in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table and a stored procedure. I use the stored procedure to update the table. There are some cursors in the stored procedure and the SP is updating the table. I want to get the rows updated by the stored procedure. I don't want to number of updated rows, I want just updated rows.

I created a temporary table to insert with updated rows but can't get the updated rows. How can I get?

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: It sounds like you would need to modify the stored procedure to stash the modified rows somewhere, like a temporary table or a log table.

Comment: Yes @GordonLinoff, I am trying to modify the sp but can't do that "this row is updated, let's insert this row the temp table"

Comment: _can't get the updated rows_ Start by explaining that in more detail. But it is not really possible to help you alter code that cannot be seen. If the procedure produces in some fashion a resultset containing the needed rows, then the issue lies in the process that executes the procedure. Based on your previous question, you should be seeking help from your more advanced or senior coworkers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your RDBMS supports it, you can use `update returning` like this:

```
sql> update your_table 
        set your_field = 'my new value' 
      where other_field = 'your condition'
     returning *; -- this returning will return a result set with the modified rows
                  -- you could also specify a list of columns here if you don't want
                  -- all fields returned
```

Using `returning` clause should work with PostgreSQL, Oracle, and others.

If you are using SQLServer (as you've just stated on your question update), you can use `output`:

```
sql> update your_table 
        set your_field = 'my new value' 
     output your_list_of_fields -- this is a comma separated list of the
                                -- columns you want to return
      where other_field = 'your condition';
```

Comment: Hi, I use MS SQL. I tried your suggestion, returning is not work. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` virtual or "psuedo" tables which are created for this purpose.  In `UPDATE` statements the virtual tables are accessible using the `OUTPUT` clause.  Here's an example

```
drop table if exists #t;
go
create table #t(col_x        char(1));

insert #t values('a');

update #t
set col_x='b'
output inserted.col_x as new_val,
       deleted.col_x as old_val;
```

```
new_val old_val
b       a
```